# PHP diz que arquivo não existe mesmo ele existindo

Tags: php

Olá, quando eu faço login eu redireciono para um arquivo chamado 'config.php' que por sua vez inclui um arquivo chamado 'usuario_dao.php'. O problema é que eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> Warning: include(/opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/centraljogos/config/dao/usuario_dao.php): failed to open stream: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado in /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/centraljogos/config/valida_login.php on line 9
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '/opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/centraljogos/config/dao/usuario_dao.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/centraljogos/config/valida_login.php on line 9
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function seleciona_usuario() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/centraljogos/config/valida_login.php on line 11

Porém o arquivo existe na pasta especificada no código. Como podem ver à seguir:

```
<?php

session_start();

//Recebe os campos da página login
$input_usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$input_senha = $_POST['senha'];

include (dirname(__FILE__) . '/dao/usuario_dao.php');

$usuario = seleciona_usuario($input_usuario, $input_senha);

//Se o resultado retornar vazio executa
if(empty($usuario))
{
    //Mensagem de erro
    $_SESSION['login_erro'] = "Usuário e/ou senha inválido(s)! Por favor, tente novamente.";
    
    //Redireciona para a tela de login
    header("Location: index.php");
}
else
{
    //Sessions que recebem os valores dos campos do banco de dados
    $_SESSION['nome_usuario'] = $aluno['nome'];
    $_SESSION['acesso_usuario'] = $aluno['permissao'];
    $_SESSION['login_usuario'] = $aluno['login'];

    $_SESSION['permissao'];
    
    if($_SESSION['acesso_usuario'] == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION['permissao'] = "Master";
        header('Location: menu.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['permissao'] = "Usuário";
        header("Location: menu_usuario.php");
    }
}
```

O arquivo está exatamente em: "/opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/centraljogos/dao/usuario_dao.php".

Ahh e esse "`dirname(__FILE__)`" eu estou usando justamente pq me indicaram que evitaria erros ao incluir diretórios. Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço bastante.

Comment: faltou um diretório aí no meio, a pasta "config": `/opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/centraljogos/config/dao/usuario_dao.php`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

## Solução rápida! É copiar e colar que funfa!

Nesse trecho:

```
include (dirname(__FILE__) . '/dao/usuario_dao.php');
```

Troque por isso:

```
include (__DIR__.'/../dao/usuario_dao.php');
```

## Solução detalhada. Cuidado, dá sono e causa confusão mental.

Na própria pergunta você aponta o path correto, o qual é diferente do path informado na mensagem de erro.

A mensagem de erro retorna:

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/centraljogos/config/dao/usuario_dao.php
```

No entanto, você mesmo informa que o path é `/opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/centraljogos/dao/usuario_dao.php`

Note que há uma pasta `config/` no path do erro.

Um jeito simples de resolver é recuando um nível:

```
include (__DIR__.'/../dao/usuario_dao.php');
```

Com isso, o path gerado é `/opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/centraljogos/config/../dao/usuario_dao.php`

Cada `../` faz o recuo de 1 diretório.

Isso faz com que o path seja apontado para

`/opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/centraljogos/dao/usuario_dao.php`

**Dica**: para maior compatibilidade, sugiro que use o `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` ao invés de definir manualmente as barras.

```
include (__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'dao'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'usuario_dao.php');
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, me ajudou bastante. Abraço!